¿Cómo puedo cerrar La cantidad de conexiones simultáneas en tiempo real a tu base de datos en realtime database de firebase?
estoy trabajando con consultas normales pero en el panel me marca que existen 19 conexiones he iniciando sesión con solo una cuenta pero la he iniciado varias veces y sigue aumentando el numero incluso después de cerrar sesión no disminuye el numero de conexiones

Hola. ¿Has programado algún código para conectar? ¿La base de datos está expuesta en algún lado?
